# Python string to int for classification

Tags: python

I am reading the book Machine Learning in Action.

One example in Chapter 2 converts string to int for classification use. For example, `'student' = 1, 'teacher' = 2, engineer = 3`.

See the code below in Line 12. While an error comes up while I execute it:

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'largeDose'

Where is my problem.

```
def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())         #get the number of lines in the file
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))        #prepare matrix to return
    classLabelVector = []                       #prepare labels return   
    fr = open(filename)
    index = 0
    for line in fr.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
        index += 1
    return returnMat,classLabelVector
```

caller code:

```
from numpy import *
import kNN
datingDataMat,datingLabels = kNN.file2matrix('datingTestSet.txt')
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.scatter(datingDataMat[:,1], datingDataMat[:,2])
ax.scatter(datingDataMat[:,1], datingDataMat[:,2], array(datingLabels),      array(datingLabels))
plt.show()
```

Traceback and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Zhiming Zhang/Documents/Machine Learning/kNN/execute.py", line 10, in <module>
    datingDataMat,datingLabels = kNN.file2matrix('datingTestSet.txt')
  File "kNN.py", line 48, in file2matrix
    classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'largeDoses'

Comment: no it's not. Just edited. thanks

Comment: This is the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'largeDose'

Comment: Please provide the error and the caller code

Comment: Please edit your post, the error and the caller code are integral part of the question.

Comment: There is thing called a trace back that tells you where your error is

Comment: Just updated. Hope it works now. This is my first time to put forward question. TThanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You try to convert a string like "largeDose" to an int using the conversion function `int()`.  But that's not how this works.  The function `int()` converts only strings which look like integer numbers (e. g. `"123"`) to integers.

In your case you can use either an `if`-`elif`-`else` cascade or a dictionary.

Cascade:

```
if listFromLine[-1] == 'largeDose':
    result = 1
elif listFromLine[-1] == 'teacher':
    result = 2
elif …
    …
else:
    result = 42  # or raise an exception or whatever
```

Dictionary:

```
conversion = {
    'largeDose': 1,
    'teacher': 2,
    … }
# ...
# later, in the loop:
classLabelVector.append(conversion[listFromLine[-1]])
# The above will raise a KeyError if an unexpected value is given.
# Ir in case you want to use a default value:
classLabelVector.append(conversion.get(listFromLine[-1], 42))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you find this answer useful, please upvote it (click on the upwards triangle besides it).  In case it actually solves your issue, please accept it (click on the check mark besides it).  And happy hacking ;-)

Comment: I tried to upvote you answer but failed. How can i accept your answer? THx!

Comment: @user6601116 As I wrote: click the check mark next to it.  Maybe this is not possible within a certain time limit after the answer was given.  But now it should be.